# How to send notification in android devices who have subscribed using firebase and android studio

Tags: android, database, firebase

I made an app in which the user can subscribe to a club but how to send notification to the user when the club posts an message(in android devices) app is made using android studio and firebase.

Comment: Have you read manual?

Comment: If you mean that documentation , then i don't understand much of it , which manual you mean otherwise?

Comment: I mean documentation. On Android app you need to override two services to receive push. On backend you need to send to firebase message with device or device group token. That's all. How to implement it? It's all described on documentation, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase Cloud Messaging

The have a good tutorial with examples

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

There is a bit of setup to your project to do so follow the instructions closely

Update:
For the device to device you can use a backend server piece.  Have one phone call the backend to sen a message to the other device. (you will need to tell it the id of the other device)

```
<?php
#API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-SERVER-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
$registrationIds = $_GET['id'];
#prep the bundle
 $msg = array
      (
    'body'  => 'Body  Of Notification',
    'title' => 'Title Of Notification',
            'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
            'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
      );
$fields = array
        (
            'to'        => $registrationIds,
            'notification'  => $msg
        );


$headers = array
        (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
#Send Response To FireBase Server   
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
?>
```

Note: $registrationIds are the device ids that should receive the mesage

Comment: I am trying so send through one android phone to another android phone , i should not use firebase console for sending notification

Comment: please see my modified answer.   You will need a server piece in between devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can send firebase push from firebase console or implement your backend that will do it, but you need to manage firebase tokens(on client side(your app) on token refresh and on server side) to do that.  read manual/guide on firebase

Comment: Can you suggest any you tube video for implement backend server for sending notification without using the firebase console

Comment: @KiritoKun take a look on firebase documentation. Dont know any video, sorry